# Pandoc-generated PDF: Change list numbering style

Tags: latex, markdown, pandoc

What is the way to change the style of numbers in ordered lists generated by Pandoc?

For the following Markdown input

```
1. One
2. Two
    1. Sub 1
    2. Sub 2
```

Pandoc generates the following Latex output

```
\begin{enumerate}
\def\labelenumi{\arabic{enumi}.}
\itemsep1pt\parskip0pt\parsep0pt
\item
  One
\item
  Two

  \begin{enumerate}
  \def\labelenumii{\arabic{enumii}.}
  \itemsep1pt\parskip0pt\parsep0pt
  \item
    Sub 1
  \item
    Sub 2
  \end{enumerate}
\end{enumerate}
```

This results in the following PDF output:

```
1. One
2. Two
    1. Sub 1
    2. Sub 2
```

While I'm trying to achieve

```
1. One
2. Two
    2.1. Sub 1
    2.2. Sub 2
```

I tried to redefine style of numbering in the default template with these commands

```
\renewcommand{\labelenumii}{\theenumii}
\renewcommand{\theenumii}{\theenumi.\arabic{enumii}.}
```

but as Pandoc generates explicit definition for `labelenumii` this solution does not work.

## Update

It turns out that the problem could be resolved by using `#.` notation instead of `1.` one. For whatever reason Pandoc skips styling only for lists defined this way and interprets the standard Markdown notation as an instruction to style list with plain numbers. Hopefully in future versions it will be a bit more flexible and will add the support for nested numbers in lists.

Comment: nice to see there is a workaround. I think your update should be an answer though, you should post it as such and accept it.

Comment: @scoa, your edit makes your answer complete thus I prefer to accept it instead of mine. Thank you for your help

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**edit**

[This function](https://github.com/jgm/pandoc/blob/master/src/Text/Pandoc/Writers/LaTeX.hs#L526) of the latex writer that adds the `\def\labelenumi{}` part checks for `numstyle == DefaultStyle && numdelim == DefaultDelim`. As @oleg found out, this might be accomplished with `#.` list markers, so that this should work:

```
---
header-includes:
- \renewcommand{\labelenumii}{\theenumii}
- \renewcommand{\theenumii}{\theenumi.\arabic{enumii}.}
---

#. One
#. Two
    #. Sub 1
    #. Sub 2
```

There are two feature requests asking for a native markdown solution on the issue tracker ([336](https://github.com/jgm/pandoc/issues/336) and [1627](https://github.com/jgm/pandoc/issues/1627)), as well as a [discussion on the mailing list](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!msg/pandoc-discuss/Ij_OkjQmmUg/7g98VtgilOIJ).

**pre-edit answer**

Of course, you could always compile to latex, postprocess the file to remove those `\def\labelenumi{}` lines, and then compile the latex file. Here is an example that works with the standard latex template.

test.md

```
---
header-includes:
- \renewcommand{\labelenumii}{\theenumii}
- \renewcommand{\theenumii}{\theenumi.\arabic{enumii}.}
---

1. One
2. Two
    1. Sub 1
    2. Sub 2
```

commands:

```
pandoc test.md -t latex -s | sed '/\\def\\labelenumi/d' > test.tex
xelatex test.tex
```

[image]

But all the lists of your document will be affected, and you need to write the latex compilation commands yourself.

Comment: Thank you for detailed answer. Looks like for now I'm stuck with default numbering as adding one more step to the compilation process would be an overkill for such a simple issue. There is one hook, though. In the code the \def instruction is generated only when style is not DefaultStyle and delimiter is not DefaultDelim. I don't know, though, how to force them to have these values

Comment: I actually do not understand why the default value is not DefaultStyle... You can test with `pandoc test.md -t native` that the list is  `OrderedList (1,Decimal,Period)`... I haven't been able to change it to default, but that might be possible.

Comment: Good point. It might be somehow connected to the actual format of a list item (e.g. using 1. instead of #. for example). I will try to experiment but this would be quite disappointing if Pandoc does not create "styleless" lists for the most common way people write lists in Markdown. My vim Markdown plugin won't be happy

Comment: Unfortunately it turns out that that is exactly what Pandoc does. If one uses '#.' as a way to mark ordered list the generated code does not have \def instruction and thus a customization is possible. I wish they have chosen to do this for standard '1.' notation instead. I will update the question and will accept your answer as it has led to the solution.